# Rails 4.1.4, script/plugin and bin/plugin is not loading

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, bash, ruby-on-rails-4, plugins

In rails 4.1.4, I am trying to install `script/plugin install git://github.com/p8/table_builder.git` plugin but I am getting an error like `bash: script/plugin: No such file or directory`.

Same command I have tried with `bin/plugin` then also I got the same error like `bash: bin/plugin: No such file or directory`

How can I install this plugin with the same(above) command? Please help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly: p8/table_builder plugin is no longer maintained. Use  this fork instead https://github.com/watu/table_builder

Secondly: You should use Gemfile to install plugins (GEMS in Ruby) and menage dependencies.

Open your Gemfile (comes with `rails new` by default) and add

`gem "watu_table_builder", :require => "table_builder"`

Save file and run `bundle install`  (or just `bundle`, it's shortcut).

Bah! It's done. Dependencies are solved and `gem` (`plugin`) is installed.

Further reading: http://bundler.io/v1.3/gemfile.html

Comment: Thank You. I have tried as you said, but now I am getting an error like `undefined method 'this_month' for #<Class:0x00000003970920>`

Comment: I believe it is gem specific question so you should go and read their README https://github.com/watu/table_builder . However my experience force me to say 'did you try to restart `rails server`' ?